# DeepLinking work but no navigate to Intended Screen using react navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I am on Android and I want to use DeepLink to open a specific screen using react navigation.

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.samtbook">

<application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
>
    <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="samtbook.me"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KET"/> // HIDDEN
</application>
```

and here is the link I use:

```
http://samtbook.me/test/
```

and I registered my deepLink like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    }

    handleOpenURL = (event) => {
    this.navigate(event.url);
    };
    navigate = (url) => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('TestScreen');
    };
```

The poblem is When the app is not running in the background(Means dead)
I click over the link and it opens the app but not navigate to intended screen 
but when the app is running in background it navigates

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use react navigation deeplinking mentioned in doc:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 1):

Http scheme is detected as a web url just change your scheme to a custom scheme for example "myapp" and change your url to myapp://samtbook.me/test/ good luck!